# Help With LINQ: Mixed Joins and Specifying Default Values

Tags: linq, join, set, default

I am trying to figure out how to do a mixed-join in LINQ with specific access to 2 LINQ objects.  Here is an example of how the actual TSQL query might look:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [User] AS [a]
INNER JOIN
  [GroupUser] AS [b]
ON
  [a].[UserID] = [b].[UserID]
INNER JOIN
  [Group] AS [c]
ON
  [b].[GroupID] = [c].[GroupID]
LEFT JOIN
  [GroupEntries] AS [d]
ON
  [a].[GroupID] = [d].[GroupID]
WHERE [a].[UserID] = @UserID
```

At the end, basically what I would like is an enumerable object full of GroupEntry objects.  What am interested is the last two tables/objects in this query.  I will be displaying Groups as a group header, and all of the Entries underneath their group heading.  If there are no entries for a group, I still want to see that group as a header without any entries.  Here's what I have so far:

So from that I'd like to make a function:

```
public void DisplayEntriesByUser(int user_id)
{
    MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();

    IEnumberable<GroupEntries> entries =
    (
        from user in db.Users
        where user.UserID == user_id
        join group_user in db.GroupUsers
          on user.UserID = group_user.UserID
        into a

        from join1 in a
        join group in db.Groups
          on join1.GroupID equals group.GroupID
        into b

        from join2 in b
        join entry in db.Entries.DefaultIfEmpty()
          on join2.GroupID equals entry.GroupID
        select entry
    );


    Group last_group_id = 0;
    foreach(GroupEntry entry in entries)
    {
        if (last_group_id == 0 || entry.GroupID != last_group_id)
        {
            last_group_id = entry.GroupID;
            System.Console.WriteLine("---{0}---", entry.Group.GroupName.ToString().ToUpper());

        }
        if (entry.EntryID)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("    {0}: {1}", entry.Title, entry.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

The example above does not work quite as expected.  There are 2 problems that I have not been able to solve:

1. I still seem to be getting an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN on the last join.  I am not getting any empty results, so groups without entries do not appear.
2. I need to figure out a way so that I can fill in the default values for blank sets of entries.  That is, if there is a group without an entry, I would like to have a mostly blank entry returned, except that I'd want the EntryID to be null or 0, the GroupID to be that of of the empty group that it represents, and I'd need a handle on the entry.Group object (i.e. it's parent, empty Group object).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Note: Table names and real-world representation were derived purely for this example, but their relations simplify what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I think it's pretty close:

```
var groupEntries =   
    from
        u in db.Users
    where
        user.Id == user_id
    join
        gu in db.GroupUsers
        on u.UserId equals gu.UserId
    join
        g in db.Groups
        on gu.GroupId equals g.GroupId
    join
        ge in db.GroupEntries
        on u.GroupdId equals ge.GroupId
        into ges
    from
        ge in ges.DefaultIfEmpty(new GroupEntry { EntryId = 0, GroupId = g.GroupId })
    select
        ge;
```

I don't think you need to use `into` unless you're planning to do some further processing, such as `DefaultIfEmpty()`. And notice that the second overload of `DefaultIfEmpty()` allows you to enter a custom default value. So, you can create a new `GroupEntry` object and assign the values you want for each property (or leave properties blank).

Comment: Thank you very much Dan.  This is a much more straightforward query.  I'm falling into some trouble later in the code behind.  My current function is expecting an IEnumberable<GroupEntries> object type through which it can iterate.  Right now, in my foreach loop, after the query, I'm getting the "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'DefaultEmpty'" error.

On a curiosity-related side note, if you use the "into" keyword in linq, does it necessarily create a subquery at the lower db layer?

Comment: Corey, is this a LinqToSql query?

Comment: Yessir. The underlying DB is an MSSQL 2005 server.

Comment: You should be able to see exactly the query being sent to SQL Server by hovering over `groupEntries` in the debugger.

Comment: Negative.  Instead, what I see is something like "entries | {System.Data.Linq.DataQuery<MyClass.GroupEntry>}".  In my actual code, I have a function that is something like "public static IEnumerable<GroupEntries> GetEntriesByUserID(int user_id) {}"  This is where the actual query is spelled out.  Even if I insert a "throw Exception("debug point")" line before the return statement, I still get the same error later in my foreach loop, I assume because of delayed evaluation:  "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'DefaultEmpty'" .  Can you tell me anything about the nature of this error?

Comment: Using the MSSQL server profiler, I can confirm that the full query never happens.  It seems that any time I pass any argument to the DefaultIfEmpty() function, I invariably get this error before the SQL is fully generated.  Once again: "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'DefaultEmpty'".

Answer (score 0):

```
  //set this to see all queries issued.
myDC.Log = Console.Out;

  //setup to load the GroupEntries property of each group
DataLoadOptions o = new DataLoadOptions();
o.LoadWith<Group>(g => g.GroupEntries);
myDC.LoadOptions = o;

  //query to get the groups
IQueryable<Group> groupQuery =
  from g in myDC.Groups
  where g.GroupUsers.Any(gu => gu.User.UserID == user_id)
  select g;
```

Comment: Hi David.  Regarding the last two sections, I must admit that this is a little above my understanding.  You are using anonymous functions (lambda expressions) here?  Would you be willing to give a quick explanation of what's going on here, or a quick link that might help to explain it?  Thanks in advance.